# Excluding dot files for s3cmd sync

Tags: s3cmd

How can I exclude all dot files in my home directory as well as those dot files in all sub-directories?

I've tried adding the following expression in my exclude file, but for some reason it does not work:

```
(^|/)\.[^/]*(/|$)
```

Also, the following doesn't work either:

```
.*
.*/**
```

Answer (score 7):

*Please try the following commands with the option `--dry-run` first to make sure that you get the result you expect.*

### Exclude .dotfiles and .folders from current directory

You can use the option `--rexclude "^\."` in order to match files and folders beginning with a `.` (But it will not match .dotfiles in a sub-directory).

Example output from `s3cmd sync --rexclude "^\." ./ s3://bucket_name`

```
exclude: .ignoreFile
exclude: .ignoreFolder/andItsContents
./normalFolder/.ignoreFile -> s3://bucket_name/normalFolder/.ignoreFile
```

The above command with exclude .dotfiles in your current folder ./  and continue to upload 
 normalFolder/.ignoreFile

### Exclude .dotfiles from sub-directories

To exclude dotfiles from a sub-directory you can use `--rexclude "\/\."`

Example output from `s3cmd sync --rexclude "\/\." ./ s3://bucket_name`

```
exclude: .ignoreThis
exclude: .ignoreFolder/.ignoreThis
exclude: .ignoreFolder/notadotfile
exclude: normalFolder/.ignoreThis
```

So the answer to your question should be similar to the following command:

```
s3cmd --rexclude "^\." --rexclude "\/\." ./ s3://bucket_name
```

Explanation of regular expression anchors used:

```
^   Start of string, or start of line in multi-line pattern
\   Escape following character
```

Useful Reference:
[Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

[s3cmd Sync HowTo](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync)

Comment: I see my problem now, thanks. I was incorrectly using regular expressions in my exclude file with --exclude-from=FILE when I should be using --**r**exclude-from=FILE.